# Image text indexing software for High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra, photos, software-recommendation

I love the Live Text feature on iOS 15 but unfortunately, my photo library is too large to fit on a Cloud account or on an iPhone - it lives on a 4Tb external hard drive.

However, I would love to be able to index photos based on the text they contain, in a similar way to Live Text, on my main computer which runs High Sierra.

I am aware of apps such as Photo Search by Alco Blom, but it doesn't run on High Sierra.

I am not looking for an OCR-only application, but for a tool that will index images in folders based on the text they contain.

Comment: You still need OCR though, to extract the text and add it to a search index, right?

Comment: Yes OCR needs to be a component of this program, but the program needs to have an indexation feature. Let me know if I can make my question clearer. I just don’t need a “OCR-only program “.

Comment: https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/devonthink maybe? Not sure they keep files where they are though.